# Comparing two Strings in Scala using > and <

Tags: string, scala

I'm trying to compare two Strings in Scala, trying to find out which comes first in the alphabet. I.e. *a* before *b*, *aab* before *abb*, etc.

It seems like the `>` and `<` operators are doing exactly this job:

> scala> "b" > "a"
>
> res14: Boolean = true
>
> scala> "b" < "a"
>
> res15: Boolean = false
>
> scala> "aab" < "abb"
>
> res16: Boolean = true

However, the [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#>(that:A):Boolean) did not enlighten me on what this really does, and none of the tutorials online seem to be using this method to compare strings. Thus, I was wondering:

- Is this a fail safe approach to do what I want to do, i.e. compare two Strings for alphabetical order?
- Is there a more common approach in Scala that I am missing here?
- How exactly does it work - e.g.

> scala> "?" > "!"
>   res25: Boolean = true

is not intuitive to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you saw in the docs, you can use the defined `>` (and all the others) for `String`s. Ultimately, this breaks down the elements of the `String` into the underlying `Char`s and they are unicode. So you need to compare the unicode values for them to emulate the logic exhibited by the scalac.

Referring to a definitive [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin) one finds that

> > U+0021   !   !  Exclamation mark

and

> > U+003F   ?   ?  Question mark

so, indeed, `!<?` is `true`.

I believe that the comparison action is failsafe for any unicode sequence that you can supply. See even:

```
val string1 = "\u2200"
val string2 = "\uFB30"

string1 < string2

val string3 = string1 + string2
val string4 = string2 + string1

string3 < string4
string4 < string3

string3 == string1 + string2
string4 == string1 + string2
```

which in my worksheet gives me:

```
string1: String = ∀
string2: String = אּ // note: aleph comes after All in the unicode definition.

res7: Boolean = true

string3: String = ∀אּ
string4: String = אּ∀

res8: Boolean = true
res9: Boolean = false

res10: Boolean = true
res11: Boolean = false
```

Comment: "I believe that the comparison action is failsafe for any unicode sequence that you can supply" If you mean it gives a consistent result and never throws an exception, yes. But this result is not the same as alphabetical ordering: just compare `"A"` and `"b"`.

Comment: I meant that it is consistent only. I attempted to explain the mechanism of ordering through the table reference and it is apparent from that table that case matters.

Comment: For the record, this is not anything special to scala or even Unicode. A traditional char comparison relying on ascii suffers from the same tendencies. Cast your strings to fully upper or lower case when comparing them :)

Answer (score 2):

> How exactly does it work

`>` and other comparison operators delegate to `compareTo` method, whose exact behavior is documented at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String). E.g. `x > y` is the same as `x.compareTo(y) > 0`.

> Is this a fail safe approach to do what I want to do, i.e. compare two Strings for alphabetical order?

No. It provides *an* order, but not the alphabetical one, if you take case (and diacritics, and...) into account. E.g. `"b" > "A"` is false.

For full alphabetical ordering, you probably want a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).
(I'd also suggest reading https://english.stackexchange.com/a/212630/26340 to start appreciating how non-trivial the rules are even just for English).

Comment: Thanks Alexey for this thorough answer! I see your point re capitalized letters etc.; I always lower-case&punctuation-clean everything pre-processing but failed to make that clear in the question ... I'll read up on the `Collator`, that seems to be what I need&didn't know about.

Comment: I recommend reading more about Unicode in general if you are dealing with natural language strings.